# cURL malformed error on POST

Tags: php, jquery

I have following code:

```
jQueryjQuery('#test').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
var empno=jQuery('#empno').val();
var msg=jQuery('#msg').val();
var rem_url="url=http://10.32.2.251/Dept/esl/rem_sms.php&msg="+ msg +"&empno="+empno; 
jQuery.post("curl_request.php", {"dest_url":rem_url },    function(data) {      
alert (data);   
});

});
```

Below is the *curl_request.php* page code.

```
<?php
//set POST variables
$url = $_POST['url'];
unset($_POST['url']);
$fields_string = "";
//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) { 
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if($result === FALSE) {
   echo curl_error($ch);
}
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The other domain page *rem_sms.php* take two parameters,msg & empno; But I am getting error  malformed. No more details . What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your javascript code. You are posting 'dest_url' variable is in php script you are using 'url'. Change the following two lines in your curl_request.php.

```
$url = $_POST['dest_url'];
unset($_POST['dest_url']);
```

Instead of

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
unset($_POST['url']);
```

Also update

```
var rem_url="url=http://10.32.2.251/Dept/esl/rem_sms.php&msg="+ msg +"&empno="+empno; BY
var rem_url="http://10.32.2.251/Dept/esl/rem_sms.php&msg="+ msg +"&empno="+empno;
```

Comment: @VikasChaudahry's answer should solve this. Also just noticed your CURLOPT_POST value is set to a numeric value but the docs state it should be boolean. Is a number greater than 0 interpreted by cURL to be truthy? Might be worth setting to true or false based on the result of the count.

Comment: I was forgot to mention that you did not you ? for adding query parameters to your url.


http://10.32.2.251/Dept/esl/rem_sms.php&msg should be like http://10.32.2.251/Dept/esl/rem_sms.php?msg=

Comment: add following code to your curl_request.php after unset($_POST['url']); ------------------------
$_parseUri = parse_url($url);
$_query = $_parseUri['query'];
parse_str($_query, $params);
--------------------------------------------
AND
replace following line ------------------------ curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($_POST)); BY --------------------------------- curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($params));